# How can I create a cp932 encoded text file on Ubuntu?

Tags: files, language-support, encoding, japanese

Is there a way to create a cp932 encoded file on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

`gedit`, "Save as" has an option to save it with a different encoding.

[image]

After that it should accept Japanese chars.

as seen here:

[image]

```
~/Desktop$ file test.txt
test.txt: DBase 3 data file with memo(s)
```

---

Command line

- convert a file to cp933:

  ```
  recode cp932 {filename}
  ```

  or

  ```
  iconv -f utf8 -t cp932 {filename} > {newfilename}
  ```

  You probably need to install `recode` with `sudo apt-get install recode`
  If you do

  ```
   touch {filename}
   recode cp932 {filename}
  ```

  you create an empty file and should be able to add cp932 chars to the file.
- If you use `vim` place the following in your `/etc/vim/vimrc` or `~/.vimrc file`:

  ```
  set encoding=cp932
  set fileencoding=cp932
  ```

  and the system will save the with cp932.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to create a cp932 encoded file from the command line? I don't have GUI access to Ubuntu

Comment: yes added those options.